# How to set Company Name and other properties for my DLL file built from Visual Studio 2010 project?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, dll

I'd expect this to be part of the Visual Studio 2010 GUI since those properties are MS Windows feature:

[image: image description]

But I see no way to configure what they contain. The most important things I need is:

- Set original name of the file
- Show build number
- Show architecture (32bit vs 64 bit)
- Show company name

I can see other programs have those properties filled in. My doesn't. Where are the project settings for it? Mine is a C++ project.

Comment: These are set in a version resource. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Whoa, VS2010 - that's *old*. Have you considered upgrading your tool chain?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'd love to, but I'm not the one to make this kind of decision. I talk about it whenever I have an opportunity.

Comment: Yes, it is in the IDE.  If you used the wrong project template then you can still easily fix it by right-clicking the project and selecting Add > New Item > Resource > Resource File (.rc).  Add the version resource.  Click around some more, it is supposed to be discoverable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the editing possibility in my resource file of the dll project.
I use VS2015, but it should be the same in that regard.

Search for Version.

In the .rc file, there sould be something like this:

```
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Version
//

VS_VERSION_INFO     VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION       1,0,0,1
PRODUCTVERSION    1,0,0,1
FILEFLAGSMASK VS_FFI_FILEFLAGSMASK
#ifdef _DEBUG
FILEFLAGS VS_FF_DEBUG
#else
FILEFLAGS 0x0L
#endif
FILEOS VOS_NT_WINDOWS32
FILETYPE VFT_DLL
FILESUBTYPE VFT2_UNKNOWN
BEGIN
BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
BEGIN
    BLOCK "040704B0"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "CompanyName", "TODO: <CompanyName>"
        VALUE "FileDescription", "TODO: <FileDescription>"
        VALUE "FileVersion",     "1.0.0.1"
        VALUE "InternalName",    "Filename.dll"
        VALUE "LegalCopyright", "TODO: (c) <CompanyName>.  All Rights reserved."
        VALUE "OriginalFilename","Filename.dll"
        VALUE "ProductName", "TODO: <ProductName>"
        VALUE "ProductVersion",  "1.0.0.1"
    END
END
BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
BEGIN
    VALUE "Translation", 0x0407, 1200
END
END
```